# Create and Bind ICommand to Mvx.MvxListView

Tags: android, android-listview, xamarin, mvvmcross, mvxbind

I am working on Xamarin Android Application.I don't know how to bind Icommand to Mvx.MvxListview.
I have tried this:

```
<Mvx.MvxListView
    android:id="@+id/AddressList"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/myaddressestemplate"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource addresslist; ItemClick ItemSelect" />
```

In ViewModel I have created Icommand like this:

```
  public  ICommand ItemSelect
    {
        get
        {
            return new MvxCommand(() => {
                ShowViewModel<CheckOutViewModel>();
            });
        }
    }
```

But When I click on ListView item nothing Runs.
Whats is the problem ? Please Help !

Comment: Change from ICommand to MvxCommand.

Comment: Use MvxCommand<TypeOfListInItem>( (item) => "code here") instead of MvxCommand(() => "code here")

Comment: I can't reproduce this error, it works fine in several of my apps.

Comment: But in my case it's not working so I had to use MvxRecyclerView@Cheesebaron

Answer (score 1):

```
public IMvxCommand ItemSelect
        {
            get
            {
                return new MvxCommand<itemModelClass>((item) =>
                {
                    ShowViewModel<CheckOutViewModel>();
                });
            }
        }
```

try, this. i think you are creating and Icommand and returning a MvxCommand.